# Search and find a word in a block of code in VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code, text-editor

I'm trying to search for a word in a block of code (a `function`, a `class`, between two `{}` and so on...) in VSCode. the default search is searching in the whole file but that is not useful in some situations.

Comment: You will need regex for that.

Comment: @HeisAif can you post an example code? Thanks!

Comment: the Find dialog has a `Find in selection` button

Comment: And there is a `Select to Bracket` command to make that part easy.

Answer (score 3):

It is easy to restrict your search key to a block of code select your block of code to search and then click on the `Find in selection` option on the find widget (left one to the close option from the image)
[See the Find in selection option here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LK41r.png)